# Как с помощью регулярных выражений выделить слова состоящие из небукв и нецифр?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярных выражений выделить слова состоящие из небукв и нецифр?

Comment: Приведите примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Непонятно, что такое слово в этом вопросе

Comment: @dIm0n, мне кажется будет более удобным давать ссылку сразу на информацию о том, как подать качественный вопрос: [о метке регулярные выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
 "\b[^\d\w]+\b"
```

На будущее указывайте какими именно регулярными выражениями пользуетесь.

\b - обозначает границу слова (может работать не во всех реализациях)

Update. В комментариях сделано замечание. Тогда правильная регулярка будет чуть сложнее.

```
/(^|(?<=\s))[^\d\w\s]+((?=\s)|$)/
```

Comment: думаю, что использовать `\b` для границы слова здесь плохая идея, потому что слова по условию состоят не из букв и не из цифр, а `\b` опирается на класс `\w`. Такая регулярка, например, не работает для строки `## ##`, где должно определиться два слова.

Comment: @AlexeyR. исправил

Comment: @AlexeyR. почему должно определиться 2 слова? Почему не одно? Ведь пробел это и небуква, и нецифра. Надо уточнить условие

Comment: @dIm0n но если считать все пробельные символы частью слова, то тогда будет результат - всегда одно большое слово.

Comment: @dIm0n Может и одно.. Хорошо бы понимать словоразделители. Но тогда не определялось ни одного :)

Comment: `\w` - эквивалент `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` в содержании которого есть `_`, который в свою очередь не совсем "буква" или "цифра", так же можно заменить `[^\w]` на `\W` - эквивалент `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, аналогично и с `\s` отрицанием будет `\S`. В добавок  в `\w` входит числовой диапазон, поэтому указывать его отдельно не имеет смысла. Пробел тоже не является буквой или цифрой, поэтому лучше бы дождаться уточнений от автора вопроса